# Missing SPFX webpart on SP2016 subsites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts

**Missing web part from the add a web part group on sub site pages.** I deployed web part to the app catalog and CDN. I’m able to use it on the top level of my website without any issues, but I can’t get the option to add the web part to appear on any sub sites. I tried adding the app to the site contents page like I did for the top level and I’m getting the error that:

> A different version of this App is already installed with the same
>   version number.  You need to delete the app from the site and the site
>   recycle bin to install this version.

Are SPFX apps only usable on the top level? Did I miss a step during the build/deployment process? I can’t seem to find any documentation or others with the same issue (on-premise) in forums. All the forum questions I'm finding are dealing with online which runs a different version of the framework. Here is my set-up:

SharePoint 2016, CDN is pointing to a site assets folder on SharePoint, and package.json...

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@pnp/spfx-property-controls": "1.14.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the app in root site and deleted it from recycle bin, and then add the app again into root site and also in the sub site.

Comment: I tried to apply the changes outlined in your link and I'm getting an error. **Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.** Also, I looked at the link you provided and that seems to only be applicable to SharePoint Online. The title reads _Use the App Catalog to make custom business apps available for your SharePoint Online environment_ so I don't think this is the correct answer.

Comment: Did you try removing the app in root site and deleted it from recycle bin, and then add the app again into root site and also in the sub site?

Comment: that worked! thank you :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I updated the answer with this.